# C# Inserting data to Access Database

Tags: c#

I am new to programming and I have a problem with inserting data from my form into the database. If I click the button, it falls into the else statement where it shows "Connection Failed".

Here is my code:

```
private void buttonAddrecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=
     C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GamefarmDB\GamefarmDB\Gamefarm.accdb;
        User ID = admin;");

    String WingbandNumber = wingbandnumberTextbox.Text;
    String DateOfHatch = dateofhatchTextbox.Text;
    String Markings = markingsTextbox.Text;
    String Bloodline = bloodlineTextbox.Text;
    String Broodhen = broodhenTextbox.Text;
    String Broodcock = broodcockTextbox.Text;

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into List (WingbandNumber, 
        DateOfHatch, Markings, Bloodline, Broodhen, Broodcock)  
        Values(@WingbandNumber, @DateOfHatch, @Markings, @Bloodline,  
        @Broodhen, @Broodcock)");

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WingbandNumber", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = WingbandNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfHatch", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = DateOfHatch;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Markings", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Markings;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bloodline", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Bloodline;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Broodhen", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Broodhen;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Broodcock", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Broodcock;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure I see a conn.Open(); Add that before the If clause and check once

Comment: You need to open the connection before you can use it. Add 'conn.Open()' before the 'if' condition.

Comment: `OleDbCommand` implements the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable). I will recomment using a `using(var con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        con.Open();
  // ...`. The using will make sure that the connection is dispose/ close properly even if an error occurs in the using code block.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your help, in the connection string I just added my password and before the **IF** statement, I added the 'conn.Open();' and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that you should have use conn.Open(); and also you should put a try catch before the if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) so your code should look like this

```
.
.
.
cmd.Connection = conn;
try
    {
       conn.Open();
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
              .
              .
              .
    else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
            }
    catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.toString());
conn.Close();
}
```

So that it will give you the exact exception why you can't connect and also it will give you an exception if anything goes wrong to the whole precedure.

Answer (score 0):

Command object requires open connection. So you should open connection before execute the command

Answer (score 0):

You need to just open the connection object before actually using it
so your code will look like this,

```
private void buttonAddrecord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source =C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\GamefarmDB\GamefarmDB\Gamefarm.accdb;User ID = admin;");
    String WingbandNumber = wingbandnumberTextbox.Text;
    String DateOfHatch = dateofhatchTextbox.Text;
    String Markings = markingsTextbox.Text;
    String Bloodline = bloodlineTextbox.Text;
    String Broodhen = broodhenTextbox.Text;
    String Broodcock = broodcockTextbox.Text;

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into List (WingbandNumber, DateOfHatch, Markings, Bloodline, Broodhen, Broodcock) Values(@WingbandNumber, @DateOfHatch, @Markings, @Bloodline, @Broodhen, @Broodcock)");

    cmd.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open(); // To Open Connection
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WingbandNumber", OleDbType.Numeric).Value = WingbandNumber;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfHatch", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = DateOfHatch;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Markings", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Markings;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Bloodline", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Bloodline;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Broodhen", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Broodhen;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Broodcock", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = Broodcock;

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Added");
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (OleDbException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Source);
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
    }
}
```